# Sweave option to hold output and flush it at the end of the chunk

Tags: r, sweave

Knitr / Quarto have an option (`results: hold`) to "[hold all pieces of text output in a chunk and flush them to the end of the chunk.](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/cells/cells-knitr.html)"

Does Sweave have a similar option?

I searched the internet, including the "[Sweave User Manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/doc/Sweave.pdf)", but haven't found anything.